# Are random samples from a markov chain independent samples from the target distribution?

Tags: markov-process

When doing MCMC, samples are not independent. The normal strategy is to retain every Nth sample for some N. The result samples should be samples from the target distribution.

What if we kept all the samples and then at the end randomly (uniformly) sampled from those?

Would we be sampling from the target distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a Markov chain $M$, which converges to some stationary distribution $\mu$.  This means that $x^TM^t\approx \mu$ when $t$ is large enough. When you run MCMC, you first have to wait for convergence to the stationary distribution. After it converges sufficiently, you sample your first point. It sounds like you're suggesting to uniformly sample from the set of points you get after sufficient convergence. This would work, so long as you have plenty of samples. This is because any finite recurrent Markov chain will spend $\mu_i$ proportion of time in state $i$, so picking a point uniformly at random is equivalent to sampling from the stationary distribution. However, your samples will always be a little correlated, since if you pick two samples that occur one after the other, they are definitely correlated.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like asymptotically both methods give you independent samples. In the non-conventional second method, the probability of selecting samples that are close to each other (with regards to the order specified by the chain) is low.  The danger of correlation is there in both methods if the number of samples is not large enough.  In retrospect, this seems self-evident. In fact, both methods may actually be equivalent in some sense. Or the second method might be considered a generalization of the conventional method. E.g/ we can add a second layer to the process of chain generation.

Comment: (continued). For each step in the chain generation process, we can with probability (for example, .001) keep the sample.  This would be a stochastic version of "keep every Nth sample"

Comment: Regarding the previous comment: this method results in a Binomial distribution over the samples rather than a uniform distribution.

Comment: you would be better off following the general practice of thinning (i.e. picking *evenly spaced* samples/samples spaced as far apart as possible), as this will generally have lower expected correlation than uniform/independent sampling.